# How to automatically keep Satis up to date with the latest dependencies from all my projects?

Tags: composer-php, satis

[Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) essentially creates a local mirror of packagist and it can download copies of all the packages you need to keep them cached.

The problem is that you have to specify all your dependencies up front. With several projects with ever-changing dependencies, keeping Satis up to date is a nightmare.

How I envisioned Satis working is that when I run `composer install` on my project it would ask Satis for a copy of each of my dependencies. If Satis didn't already have it cached, it would query Packagist, download a copy, and then serve it to me. The next time I install it would be cached. If Pacakgist then goes down, or the project maintainer deletes his repo off Github, it won't matter because Satis has kept a copy.

Is there a way to make Satis behave this way? Or is there an alternative Packagist mirror that does this?

Answer (score 0):

How to make Satis update what it stores? Run it more than once.

In fact, it should run as a job in your build infrastructure, probably at least once per day.

If you want auto-updating for everything you use, you could also have a look at [Toran proxy](https://toranproxy.com/).